# Apache basic authentication on Django site

Tags: django, apache

I'm trying to add basic Apache name/password authentication to a running Django site.

I've following the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371716/django-protect-some-web-paths-with-basic-authentication). I've created an .htpasswd file and have the following in httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ann/webapps/django/domesday.wsgi
<Directory /home/ann/webapps/apache2>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/ann/webapps/django/domesday/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

However, when I try to start Apache, I get the error message:

```
[annaps@web121 apache2]$ bin/restart 
Apache isn't running.
Syntax error on line 25 of /home/annaps/webapps/django/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'AuthUserFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, this is an exact copy of all the examples.

I don't need to specify paths to protect - just the whole site is fine. I'm not totally sure what to put in the `<Directory`> tag though - the root of my Django project, the root of Apache (as here), or something else?

Answer (score 2):

From http://readthefuckingmanual.net/error/1385/ (I didn't pick that URL intentionally I swear!):

Make sure you have this in your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
```

Comment: Thank you. That solves the error message but unfortunately I now have a 500 error. If I comment out the <Directory> part it goes away. Any ideas? :(

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for the server?  What do they say?

Answer (score 0):

`AuthUserFile` is part of `mod_authn_file`, which is only available in 2.1. Make sure that the module is loaded if it exists. And if it doesn't... you won't be able to use that directive.